# How to delete cookies on domains with a leading dot with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Google analytics sets cookies called _ga but it sets them on the domain with a leading dot.

So neither of these work:

```
document.cookie = "_ga=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;domain=.example.com";
document.cookie = "_ga=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

Is there a way to delete these? I'm trying to offer users the option to delete cookies (and opt out of tracking).

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie) "Contrary to earlier specifications, leading dots in domain names are ignored", so I don't understand why that dot is showing anyway.

### Edit

#### Chrome (80, Ubuntu)

Setting the expired blank `_ga` cookie on the domain *with leading dot* works, although the cookies inspector panel does not update - you have to force that UI to reload to show that the cookie is now updated/gone. (Also, see Petr's comment.)

As can be seen in the chrome console screenshot below, the `_ga` cookie is shown, then is deleted.

[image: screenshot of Chrome console]

#### Firefox (75, Ubuntu)

For convenience, I tried to delete the `prov` cookie on `.stackoverflow.com`. This did not delete. I don't know if it's relevant but `document.cookies` does not list it either. I also tried the `_ga` cookie, same:
[image: screenshot from firefox]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I just tried your method on this stackoverflow.com page and it seemed to work without any issues in current Chrome (80.0.3987.132) in Windows 8.1. The cookie expiration time was updated correctly. `document.cookie = "_ga=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;domain=.stackoverflow.com";`

Comment: Hmmm. I'm trying on firefox to no avail. Will try chrome (but I need a x-browser solution)

Comment: I tried it in Firefox (52.9.0, 32-bit) at work and it worked correctly as well. The behaviour differs from Chrome though. Chrome only updates the expriation date of the cookie, while Firefox immediately completely removes the cookie.